# Concatenate C string for postgresql

Tags: c, postgresql

So I'm trying to build my sql statement in the for loop.
But on executing, it shows error at the very first point of the string.
Is the concatenation method wrong, cause I printed the sql statement and manually execute in postgresql and it works.

Also I had tried

```
char *sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO record()..VALUES();\
    INSERT INTO record()..VALUES();\
    INSERT INTO record()..VALUES();
"
```

That works.

*Note that I have reduced the loop to only once and reduced the number of columns for brevity.*

The code:

```
char sqlStatement[8000];
for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
        sprintf(&sqlStatement[0] + strlen(sqlStatement), "INSERT INTO record (\"user_id\", \"filename\", \"ports\", \"timestamp\" ... )VALUES (1, 'example%d', 0, '123456789%d', ... );", i, i,);
}
pgResult = PQexec(pgConn, sqlStatement);
if (PQresultStatus(pgResult) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
        printf("%s", PQresultErrorMessage(pgResult));
        PQclear(pgResult);
        closeSQL(pgConn);
        exit(-1);
}
```

Error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""
LINE 1: INSERT INTO captures ("user_id", "filename", "ports", "time...        
        ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `strlen(sqlStatement)` but `sqlStatement` is uninitialized at that point. That's undefined behavior.

Put

```
sqlStatement[0] = '\0';
```

before the loop to start out with an empty string.

By the way, `exit(-1)` is wrong. The only standard C exit values are `0`/`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. On Unix you can use any value between `0` and `255`. I'm not sure about Windows but it's probably similar. I don't know any OS where `-1` is valid.

Comment: Ah...that solved my headache. Thanks!
Will change the exit to the standard method too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char sqlStatement[11111];
size_t_pos;

pos=0; 
pos += sprintf(sqlStatement+pos, "INSERT INTO record() VALUES(%s);\n" , "Argh!" );
pos += sprintf(sqlStatement+pos, "INSERT INTO record(...);\n" ... );
pos += sprintf(sqlStatement+pos, "INSERT INTO record(...);\n" ... );
...
```

A real program should of course first check the return value from sprintf, before using it to increment the `pos` position.